# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, php

I have made a backup of all archives from ftp, deleted them all them copied all folders to the same place.

**Now I got this error:** `Warning: require(/../private/shADMIN/fuel/app/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/homol/web/index.php on line 11 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/../private/shADMIN/fuel/app/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/homol/web/index.php on line 11`

I already have set-up all permissions correctly.
What should I look into?

On index.php:

```
error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    define('DOCROOT', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    define('APPPATH', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../fuel/app/') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    define('PKGPATH', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../fuel/packages/') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    define('COREPATH', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../fuel/core/') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    defined('FUEL_START_TIME') or define('FUEL_START_TIME', microtime(true));
    defined('FUEL_START_MEM') or define('FUEL_START_MEM', memory_get_usage());
    echo APPPATH;
    //require APPPATH.'bootstrap.php';
    require '/var/www/homol/private/shADMIN/fuel/app/bootstrap.php';
```

echo APPAPPPATH only prints "/";